# Run python + scrapy from php

Tags: python, php, scrapy

I have a script in python. It parses site with scrapy (https://docs.scrapy.org/).

If i run it from command line on local machine or on server it works. It is strange behaviour, cause it writes logs after start however shouldn't, but it works.

If i run same script from site on php (`nginx + php7.4-fpm + symfony 4.4`) it is not running. I am checking status (`ps waux | grep python`) but the list is empty.

I even created separate bash script and trying to do same using it, but i have save.
This bash script contain php command line app call, this app is working but python app is not.

Comment: how are you running the script from the php?

Comment: using exec function

Answer (score 0):

Actually i figured out why it is not working.

Php does not know anything about python path, so if you run it something like next `python3 /full/path/to/script.py` it will not work.

You must enter full python path, like next `/usr/local/bin/python3 /full/path/to/script.py`.

I changed this in my scripts and they started working.